# CORS impossible on AWS Lambda HTTP API Gateway Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

An AWS Lamba function (NodeJS) returning 3 HTTP headers: aaa, Access-Control-Allow-Origin and bbb was created:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { "aaa":"aaa", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*", "bbb":"bbb" },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

The function is integrated into a HTTP API (not REST API). In the HTTP API Gateway Configuration, Section "Configure CORS", the HTTP header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" was set to "*". Please see the screenshot:

[Gateway Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpg3O.png)

The command "curl -i https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" proves that the HTTP Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin is explicitly removed, because only HTTP headers aaa and bbb are returned:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 11:01:58 GMT
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 20
aaa: aaa
bbb: bbb
apigw-requestid: K-S2EjVWliAEJKw=
```

Why on earth is this header still not present, even after "Configure CORS" was done?

(I'm googling now for more than two days in order to find a solution and it makes me go nuts)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [Configuring CORS for an HTTP API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html) -

> If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway ignores CORS headers
>   returned from your backend integration.

That's why the CORS headers from your Lambda (integration) are being ignored. This is one of the differences between the new HTTP APIs from the original REST APIs. In case of these APIs -

> For a CORS request, API Gateway adds the configured CORS headers to
>   the response from an integration.

When you do a simple curl, that is not actual doing a cross-origin request. Hence, you don't see the CORS headers that would be set by the HTTP API. To verify if a CORS request works, I passed an *Origin* header in the below request and I can see the CORS headers along with my custom headers from Lambda -

```
$ curl -v -X GET https://$API_ID.execute-api.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com -H "Origin: https://www.example.com"

< HTTP/2 200
< date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 18:02:26 GMT
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 18
< aaa: aaa
< bbb: bbb
< access-control-allow-origin: https://www.example.com
< access-control-expose-headers: date, x-api-id
```

Below is a snippet of my CORS configuration on the API. I added  Access-Control-Allow-Origin value as https://www.example.com and passed this as a part of the Origin header in my curl request. Such a request would qualify as CORS.

[image]

Comment: This is not working when I try it. Are you sure this is enough?

Comment: @SimonGuldstrand Can you share sample curl request and output? Was your API deployed with the latest change?

Comment: Yes it was deployed, no more CORS settings on the API itself.
See image: https://imgur.com/a/GaIuocq
Can we chat somewhere and I will link the output from curl etc

Comment: @SimonGuldstrand Why are your CORS settings blank? Aren't you trying to set CORS headers here?

Comment: @SurajBhatia Thank you a million times! Is it CORS official standard to only send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header, when the request contains an Origin HTTP header, or is this an AWS special behavior?

Comment: @JohnSteel It's in general how CORS works (nothing specific to AWS). Read more about Origin header here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

Answer (score 7):

For POST/PUT requests, you'll need to white list the `content-type` header.
Putting the wildcard doesn't do the trick for some reason, you need to explicitly whitelist it.

[image: apigw configuration]

Comment: Life saver!  Thanks a million Elad for your comment, I've been turning around in circles when only that specific content-type allowed header was required to be updated 

Answer (score 7):

For Googlers:

If your `OPTIONS` preflights succeed but no `Access-Control-` headers present, and if you are testing using CURL, take extra attention to spell required headers for a preflight:

- Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
- Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
- Origin: https://theaws.blog

If wrongly spelt, `OPTIONS` succeeds with `204 No Content`, but no `Access-Control-` headers thus render the preflight result invalid.

Also check you have enough scope for the parameters, as long as your requested method and headers are a subset of the parameter, you will get `Access-Control-` headers. If not, you will get `204 No Content` instead, which I would say it's not very informative!