# AWS::Serverless::HttpApi Cors configuration working for POST but not OPTIONS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-sam, aws-http-api

I have been fighting CORS for a while now and I have run out of ideas. I have a `AWS::Serverless::HttpApi` deployed through SAM. This API has only one endpoint for now, it takes a POST request to `/auctions`. Testing in PostMan it works, but of course testing anywhere else throws the dreaded `preflight failed` error. The past couple of day I have been trying different things and nothing has worked. Here is the current state of my `template.yaml`:

```yaml
Resources:

  AdminApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration:
        AllowMethods:
          - GET
          - POST
          - OPTIONS
        AllowOrigins:
          - "*"
        AllowHeaders:
          - "*"

  OptionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: handlers/options.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Events:
        ApiPost:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AdminApi
            Path: /auctions
            Method: options

  CreateAuctionFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: handlers/create_auction.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Events:
        ApiPost:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AdminApi
            Path: /auctions
            Method: post
      Environment:
        Variables:
          AUCTION_TABLE: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/applications/tikes/${Stage}/ddb/Auctions/TableName}}"
      Policies:
        - SSMParameterReadPolicy:
            ParameterName: !Sub "applications/tikes/${Stage}/*"
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/applications/tikes/${Stage}/ddb/Auctions/TableName}}"
```

This template has a sibling template creating the DynamoDb table, I'm omitting it because that part is working fine. Here is the options lambda handler (adding a body had no effect on the headers):

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

And the success response I send from the POST handler:

```py
def success_body(auction_id):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({
            'auction_id': auction_id
        }),
    }
```

Before adding the options lambda handler I was receiving a `204` response from the OPTIONS request without the allow-origin header, now that I added the handler I get a `200` as expected, however the header is still not there. With this configuration, sending a request with the same headers through PostMan will have the header on POST, but it will be missing with the OPTIONS request.

Things I have tried:

1. `CorsConfiguration: true`
2. Hard-coding an origin

Things I've read:

1. [Fix CORS "Response to preflight..." header not present with AWS API gateway and amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812208/fix-cors-response-to-preflight-header-not-present-with-aws-api-gateway-and)
2. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/
3. https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/
4. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/configuring-cors-on-amazon-api-gateway-apis/
5. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/
6. https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2637
7. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=252972
8. [CORS impossible on AWS Lambda HTTP API Gateway Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188770/cors-impossible-on-aws-lambda-http-api-gateway-integration)
9. Any other aws cors question I could find.

The fact that the header is present in the POST request tells me that *something* is working. I just can't figure out why it works for one request but not the other.